# Registering your app in Teams is failing with error "You don't have permissions to add Hello World to this team."

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams, microsoft-appstudio

I am following [Get started on the Microsoft Teams platform with Node.js and App Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tutorials/get-started-nodejs-app-studio)

to add app in MSTeams. All the steps worked as per the documentation, however the last step "Register your app in Teams" failed during installing of the application. Below is the image attached
[image]

I also tried to upload the custom application , but it also throws error that something went wrong.
Below are the images:
[image]
[image]

Here are the permissions, I have enabled them all to test, still the issue remains the same
[image]

Can someone please suggest to fix this issue?

Comment: Can you verify you followed the steps in the Prepare your Environment section? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tutorials/get-started-nodejs-app-studio#prepare-your-development-environment

Comment: I tried it multiple times now :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure that you have the correct permissions to side-load custom apps into Teams, and this can be controlled at the Org (i.e. Tenant) level, the Team level, and the individual level. Have a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/teams-custom-app-policies-and-settings#org-wide-custom-app-setting) for more.

Comment: I am using Mac OS  version of MSTeams and unfortunately I could not locate these settings at all in my MS Teams. Is it possible to share screenshot?

Comment: @RDX- These settings are part of [ Microsoft Teams admin center](https://admin.teams.microsoft.com/policies/app-setup/). First of all, you need to [Allow interaction with custom apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/teams-custom-app-policies-and-settings#org-wide-custom-app-setting).